# Find out if string contains a combination of letters in a specific order

Tags: python, substring

I am attempting to write a program to find words in the English language that contain 3 letters of your choice, in order, but not necessarily consecutively. For example, the letter combination `EJS` would output, among others, the word `EJectS`. You supply the letters, and the program outputs the words.

However, the program does not give the letters in the right order, and does not work at all with double letters, like the letters FSF or VVC. I hope someone can tell me how I can fix this error.

Here is the full code:

```
with open("words_alpha.txt") as words:
    wlist = list(words)
while True:
    elim1 = []
    elim2 = []
    elim3 = []
    search = input("input letters here: ")
    for element1 in wlist:
        element1 = element1[:-1]
        val1 = element1.find(search[0])
        if val1 > -1:
            elim1.append(element1)
    for element2 in elim1:
        val2 = element2[(val1):].find(search[2])
        if val2 > -1:
            elim2.append(element2)
    for element3 in elim2:
        val3 = element3[((val1+val2)):].find(search[1])
        if val3 > -1:
            elim3.append(element3)
    print(elim3)
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: the letters are not in the right order and it returns erroneous data if two letters in the key for the word are the same

Comment: please provide the words_alpha.txt file for me to reproduce the problem. apparently, you code has a lot of bugs

Comment: download it from https://github.com/dwyl/english-words

Comment: when i do `wlist = list(words)`, it returns a list of all the words but all the words have \n on the end. this removes them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making this very complicated for yourself. To test whether a word contains the letters E, J and S in that order, you can match it with the regex `E.*J.*S`:

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.search('E.*J.*S', 'EJectS')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 6), match='EJectS'>
>>> re.search('E.*J.*S', 'JEt engineS') is None
True
```

So here's a simple way to write a function which tests for an arbitrary combination of letters:

```py
import re

def contains_letters_in_order(word, letters):
    regex = '.*'.join(map(re.escape, letters))
    return re.search(regex, word) is not None
```

Examples:

```py
>>> contains_letters_in_order('EJectS', 'EJS')
True
>>> contains_letters_in_order('JEt engineS', 'EJS')
False
>>> contains_letters_in_order('ABra Cadabra', 'ABC')
True
>>> contains_letters_in_order('Abra CadaBra', 'ABC')
False
```

If you want to test every word in a wordlist, it is worth doing `pattern = re.compile(regex)` once, and then `pattern.search(word)` for each word.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the file correctly with `read()`, and since there is a newline between each word, call `split('\n')` to properly create the word list. The logic is simple. If all the letters are in the word, get the index for each letter, and check that the order of the indexes matches the order of the letters.

```py
with open('words_alpha.txt') as file:
    word_list = file.read().split('\n')

search = input("input letters here: ").lower()
found = []
for word in word_list:
    if all(x in word for x in search):
        i = word.find(search[0])
        j = word.find(search[1], i + 1)
        k = word.find(search[2], j + 1)
        if i < j < k:
            found.append(word)
print(found)
```

Using Function:

```py
def get_words_with_letters(word_list, search):
    search = search.lower()
    for word in word_list:
        if all(x in word for x in search):
            i = word.find(search[0])
            j = word.find(search[1], i + 1)
            k = word.find(search[2], j + 1)
            if i < j < k:
                yield word

words = list(get_words_with_letters('fsf'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you're using `val1` from a specific word in your first loop for another word in your second loop. So `val1` will be the wrong value most of the time as you're using the position of the first letter in the last word you checked in your first loop for every word in your seconds loop.

There are a lot of ways to solve what you're trying to do. However, my code below should be fairly close to what you had in mind with your solution. I have tried to explain everything that's going on in the comments:

```py
# Read words from file
with open("words_alpha.txt") as f:
    words = f.readlines()

# Begin infinite loop
while True:

    # Get user input
    search = input("Input letters here: ")

    # Loop over all words
    for word in words:

        # Remove newline characters at the end
        word = word.strip()

        # Start looking for the letters at the beginning of the word
        position = -1

        # Check position for each letter
        for letter in search:
            position = word[position + 1:].find(letter)

            # Break out of loop if letter not found
            if position < 0:
                break

        # If there was no `break` in the loop, the word contains all letters
        else:
            print(word)
```

For every new letter we start looking beginning at `position + 1` where `position` is the position of the previously found letter. (That's why we have to do `position = -1`, so we start looking for the first letter at `-1 + 1 = 0`.)

You should ideally move the removal of `\n` outside of the loop, so you will have to do it once and not for every search. I just left it inside the loop for consistency with your code.

Also, by the way, there's no handling of uppercase/lowercase for now. So, for example, should the search for `abc` be different from `Abc`? I'm not sure, what you need there.